# null type and compiler error in c

Tags: c, file, io, compiler-errors, null

I used a online compiler to compile the following code, and it throws an error that says: " â null undeclared (first use in this function)" I don't quite understand where the problem lies, as I thought we don't need to declare null.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   FILE *f; 
   f=fopen(argv[1],"r"); 
   char string[17];
   while (fgets(string,17,f)!=null ){
  ........
```

Comment: `null != NULL`.

Comment: null in your code, should be `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
while (fgets(string,17,f)!=null ){

}
```

to

```
while (fgets(string,17,f)!=NULL ){

}
```

btw: for next problems, you can use this site

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

there are many and good examples for c functions

Answer (score 4):

The check should be against `NULL` not null.

```
while (fgets(string,17,f)!=NULL )
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says: the compiler does not know the symbol `null`.
The reason: there is no symbol `null` defined by the c standard.

You may (the recommended way) use `NULL` that is defined in `stddef.h` or make your own define.

Comment: The C-Standard say `NULL` should be defined in `stddef.h`.

Answer (score -1):

There is no `null` in C.

You want to use `NULL`.

The C Standard defines `NULL` to be `#define`d as a macro in `stddef.h`:

> **7.19 Common Defintions < stddef.h>**
>
> [...]
>
> 3 The macro [...] [is]
>   NULL
>   which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant;